# How to implement an Interface in another class in main_activity if main_activity already implements ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: java, android, interface, android-actionbar

my MainActivity is

```
   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
```

I have a class called FragmentA which extends Fragment and it has an interface called

```
    public interface OnListSelectedListener{
    public void onListSelected(String id);
}
```

how can i use this  `onListSelected(String id)` in MainActivity???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
ActionBar.TabListener, OnListSelectedListener {

      @Override
      public void onListSelected(String id) {

      }
   }
```

This should fix your problem

Comment: OnListSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type
tried FragmentA.OnListSelectedListener
still the same

Comment: Then you did not implement your OnListSelectedListener or you did not import it, could it be that you mean the OnItemSelectedListener of android?